# Gradle build failing in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:createDebugMainDexClassList'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

My build.gradle is,

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.izabuy"
        minSdkVersion 14
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 21
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/drummer-aidan/maven' }

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
        compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.7'
        compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
        compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
        compile 'com.etsy.android.grid:library:1.0.5'
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
        compile project(':AviarySDK')
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.1.1'}
    }
```

I did not get what is the problem in this. If I build, rebuild and clean the project everything was ok. But when I run the application above message display. I tried everything but still error display. Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

remove JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
and then sync gradle
should work

Answer (score 1):

```
 compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

Remove these lines